# Using software-properties-gtk returnes dbus.proxies

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-20.04, xfce

I currently get the following error when I launch `software-properties-gtk` or `sudo software-properties-gtk` on xubuntu 20.04.

```
    /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.7) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.452:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 222, in __init__
    self.backend.Reload();
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 72, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 141, in __call__
    return self._connection.call_blocking(self._named_service,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.452 was not provided by any .service files
```

I have already tried these solutions but they did not work:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-six python3-certifi`

`sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I tried reinstalling all the packages, even the python ones and nothing worked.
So I read the code in /lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py and commenting out line **222** everything worked again!!!
**self.backend.Reload(); --> # self.backend.Reload();**